# Is it good behavior in Monotouch to use a new NSAutoReleasePool() as often as possible?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Wondering: to support MT, is it good design/behavior to encapsulate code into  `NSAutoReleasePool`() as often as possible?
Or do the same rules apply as for ObjC: create one if you loop a lot of data, creating and disposing many objects or when creating new threads?
When the scope of an `NSAutoReleasePool` ends, will MT release memory immediately, or will it release whenever it has time to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created fairly large apps in MonoTouch, that load a lot of data (some in the few megabytes multiple times), and I didn't have to bother with NSAutoReleasePool at all.. In general, the MonoTouch garbage collector works pretty well, and handles most of the work for you.

A few times I run the `GC.Collect()` method myself so I know data is released straight away, but that happens in very few cases.

It all depends on how you design your app. If the only parts of the Apple framework that you use are for UI, you don't really need to care, as they'll always be created/destroyed in the main UI thread, and automatically assigned an NSAutoReleasePool. If you do use other Apple frameworks in a separate thread, then you need to have the object in place.

Comment: Does it make sense to run GC.Collect()? Can you see any positive effect?